# Iterate through ObservableCollection of class

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm assigning values to a class by using ObservableCollection.Class contains MainItems and it's SubItems. Now how can I read all SubItems for each input of MainItem?

```
 public class MainItems
   {
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SubItems> SubItemsList { get; set; }
   }
   public class SubItems
   {
    public string SubItemName { get; set; }
   }

  ObservableCollection<MainItems> _data = new   ObservableCollection<MainItems>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            MainItems _mainItems = new MainItems();
            _mainItems.ItemName = "Main" + i.ToString();
            _mainItems.SubItemsList = new ObservableCollection<SubItems>();
            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            {
                SubItems _subItems = new SubItems()
                {
                    SubItemName = "SubItem" + i.ToString()
                };
                _mainItems.SubItemsList.Add(_subItems);
            }
            _data.Add(_mainItems);
        }
```

Comment: use two foreach loops?

Comment: yes, Main1 > SubItem1,SubItem1,SubItem1. Main2 > SubItem2,SubItem2,SubItem2, Main3>SubItem3,SubItem3,SubItem3.Main4->SubItem4,SubItem4,SubItem4,

Comment: @DIVYAHARI - The same way you have assigned above. That is what Fang meant.

Comment: you use 2 loops to fill the collections, almost the same way you would do it to read or access them. The outer loop would run until `i < _data.Count ` and the inner loop would run until `j < _data[i].SubItemsList.Count`

Comment: That loops may vary. I want to iterate from   ObservableCollection<MainItems> _data

Comment: this is why you need to use the [List.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) property to find you how many elements are in your list and run the loop for exactly that many times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foreach loop alway honors the collections(List, Array, Dictionary(special), ...) boundaries and iterates over all Elements, so its the shortest way to achieve what you want. It disallows you to add/remove elements from the currently iterated collection. In this case the classic for loop is your friend.

Full description from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

Based on Fangs comment:

```
// foreach Version
foreach (MainItems mainItem in _data)
{
    foreach (SubItems subItems in mainItem.SubItemsList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{mainItem.ItemName} has a child {subItems.SubItemName}!");
    }
}

// for Version
for (int i = 0; i < _data.Count; i++)
{
    MainItems mainItem = _data[i];
    for (int k = 0; k < mainItem.SubItemsList.Count; k++)
    {
        SubItems subItem = mainItem.SubItemsList[k];
        Console.WriteLine($"{mainItem.ItemName} has a child {subItem.SubItemName}!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I little explanation would really boost the quality of your answer

Answer (score 0):

// For Enumerator version

// get the input main item

```
string input = "Main1";

    IEnumerable<ObservableCollection<SubItems>> ItemsforSelectedMainIem = _data.Where(x => x.ItemName == input).Select(x => x.SubItemsList);
    var e = ItemsforSelectedMainIem.GetEnumerator();
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        var v = e.Current.Select(x=>x.SubItemName).ToList();
        foreach (var item in v)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```